# eclipse import android project problems

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I try to import an `android project`, and i got this `console message` !!

```
**[2015-05-15 08:36:16 - CabBookingHome]** C:\Users\FAMILLE\Desktop\r21\CabBookingHome\res\values\strings.xml:104: error: Resource entry register_me is already defined.

**[2015-05-15 08:36:16 - CabBookingHome]** C:\Users\FAMILLE\Desktop\r21\CabBookingHome\res\values\base_strings.xml:10: Originally defined here.

**[2015-05-15 08:36:16 - CabBookingHome]** C:\Users\FAMILLE\Desktop\r21\CabBookingHome\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

can any one help me please :) thank you

Comment: Looks like you need to reference appcompat. I suggest you switch to android studio now.

Comment: i have tried to switch to android studio , i import the project ( import project from ADT -eclipse android- )  and it  shows me this message !!


 * Project CabBookingHome:C:\Users\FAMILLE\Desktop\studio\CabBookingHome\project.properties:
Library reference ..\google-play-services_lib could not be found
Path is C:\Users\FAMILLE\Desktop\studio\CabBookingHome\..\google-play-services_lib which resolves to C:\Users\FAMILLE\Desktop\studio\google-play-services_lib
how do i proceed ?